# FIle download even when extension is not entered

Tags: apache

In apache, I can do something very strange. Imagine I have a folder named 'dir' and that inside it there there is the file '123.zip'. If i get to a browser and write in the URL bar 'http://mydomain.com/dir/123.zip' I download the file as it is suposed to happen, but if I type 'http://mydomain.com/dir/123' instead, I download the file as well. Is this suposed to happen? If so, is there any way to deactivate it?

Comment: Well, that would be the sort of thing you would look up in the configuation files for Apache, and the documentation. Apache allows you to (de)compress files on the fly when they are requested. Check your settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might you have [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) enabled?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is that what enables this behavior?